# Add two columns in pandas with different output depending on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose we have to following pandas dataframe

```
asd = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', np.nan, 'c', np.nan], 'B':['f', np.nan, 'u', 'i', np.nan]})
```

I want to concat the values in columns 'A' and 'B' and put a comma ',' between them and put it into a new column asd['C'] if they are both are notnull(). Otherwise return either if the other one isnull(), or return np.nan if both are null() so the final outcome for column 'C' would be

```
asd['C'] = ['a, f', 'b', 'u', 'c, i', np.nan]
```

I tried the following

```
def f(asd):
if asd['A'].notnull() & asd['B'].notnull():
    asd['C'] = asd['A'] + ', ' + asd['B']
elif asd['A'].notnull() & asd['B'].isnull():
    asd['C'] = asd['A']
elif asd['A'].isnull() & asd['B'].notnull():
    asd['C'] = asd['B']
else:
    asd['C'] = np.nan
return asd['C']

asd['C'] = asd.apply(f, axis=1)
```

but it is giving me the following error

```
("'str' object has no attribute 'notnull'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply` + `str.join`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()), 1).replace('', np.nan)

0    a, f
1       b
2       u
3    c, i
4     NaN
dtype: object
```

The final `replace` call handles your `np.nan` requirement.

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you again and again @COLDSPEED you are saving me a lot of time

Comment: @MartinHeusen No worries. I am just a little disappointed pandas doesn't inherently support `str` methods across subslices or this could've been sped-up a lot.

Comment: yeah I know, apply() functionality always slow things down especially when dealing with dataframes with 10s of millions of rows like the problem I'm tackling.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ add a new way ..since `np.nan` create a lot of problem here..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this way ..

```
df['C']=df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
df
Out[459]: 
     A    B    C
0    a    f  a,f
1    b  NaN    b
2  NaN    u    u
3    c    i  c,i
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Add timing :

small Data set:

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()), 1).replace('', np.nan)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop
%timeit df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 ms per loop
```

Large data set (both slow)

```
df=pd.concat([df]*1000,axis=1)
df=pd.concat([df]*1000,axis=0)
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()), 1).replace('', np.nan)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.1 s per loop
%timeit df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(','.join)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.23 s per loop
```

Comment: I can see this as a good alternative. I am not sure about it speedwise... it would be interesting to see timings here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ add timing ~ :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'd say the slow speed of the second is due to the stack operation. But good one nonetheless.